# delete json element in a array of json c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of json from the server. Like

```
ArrayExp = [
  {
    "id" : "number",
    "name" : "a name",
    ...
  }, 
  {
    "id" : "number",
    "name" : "a name",
    ...
  },
...
];
```

And I want to remove a "id" from all of the Array. I am trying with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ArrayExp.Length; i++) {
    ArrayExp[i].id // I don't know how to remove it!
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Start by not mixing JS and C#.

Comment: ArrayExp.RemoveAt(i);
If you are on c#

Comment: @HenkHolterman In c# you can do a loop like in js. The array is an example and I can do the `ArrayExp[i].id` to select the id from the object in c# . What do you mean?

Comment: @AamirNakhwa But I want to remove only the "id" in all object, not all of the object

Comment: I mean that `[{"id" : "number",` won't compile in C#. Post the actual class(es). Best to write a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayExp` elements are objects of [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types).

In order to remove property on it, you should map each element into new one without `id`.

```
var newArrayExpr = 
          ArrayExp
              .Select(it => new { it.name, ... });
```

Comment: it could be ok but I don't know if in the future the elements would change, I need do it without the name of elements... Only the "id" name

Answer (score 0):

I used [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) from System.Dynamic, hope it helps you

```
public static void Main()
{
    var arrayExp = GetArray();
    var newCollection = ArrayExp.ToList().Select(x => RedefineObject(x, "Id"));
}

static object[] GetArray()
{
    var person1 = new { Name = "name", Id = 1 };
    var person2 = new { Name = "name", Id = 2 };
    var person3 = new { Name = "name", Id = 3 };
    return new[] { person1, person2, person3 };
}

static object RedefineObject(object obj, string propertyToRemove)
{
    var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name != propertyToRemove);

    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var eobj = new ExpandoObject();
    var eoColl = (ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)eobj;

    properties.ToList().ForEach(x => dict.Add(x.Name, x.GetValue(obj)));

    dynamic dynObj = dict;
    return dynObj;
}
```